# mongo connection error inside mongoS container

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, mongo-shell

I'm trying to orchestrate a MongoDB cluster inside Kubernetes, working with StatefulSets and Headless Services. It's been a while I'm trying to figure out what's wrong in this but can't find anything I could use.

While doing my research I found [this repository](https://github.com/pkdone/gke-mongodb-shards-demo) which I cloned and adapted to the use case. You can find one of the manifests (the one for the mongoS instance) [right here](https://pastebin.com/XsM02DvS).

I then run the `generate.sh` script shipped within the repository, but with everything related to `gcloud` or `persistentVolume` commented, leaving only the `statefulSet`/`Service` spawning processes. Everything seems to be working fine, but whenever the script reaches the block

```
# Wait for the mongos to have started properly
echo "Waiting for the first mongos to come up (`date`)..."
echo " (IGNORE any reported not found & connection errors)"
echo -n "  "
until kubectl --v=0 exec mongos-router-0 -c mongos-container -- mongo --quiet --eval 'db.getMongo()'; do
    sleep 2
    echo -n "  "
done
echo "...first mongos is now running (`date`)"
echo
```

It just gives this error message indifenitely:

```
2019-03-11T14:02:03.531+0000 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:343:13
@(connect):1:21
exception: connect failed
command terminated with exit code 1
```

Thus I tried to run `mongo` from inside the pod directly, but the same error happened. Then I just tried to run `mongo` using different ports just inside the container, running `mongo --port 27018` (also tried 27019 and 27020), just to see which kind of errors it gives with non-exposed ports, and it seems that it gives the same error.

How could I run mongo inside a container with a running mongos on port 27017? It seems that I have to run `mongod` before running the `mongo` shell, even if `mongos` already started. It's really mind-boggling and I feel like I'm missing something. I only have this error inside the mongos pods, while the mongo-configdb and mongod-maindb seems to be running smoothly (and running the mongo shell inside them doesn't give any errors. Moreover, when doing `rs.status()` inside one of those it works fine).

You can find some `mongos` logs [there](https://pastebin.com/6pHGaFac).

**TL;DR** 
How could I run mongo inside a container with a running mongos on port 27017?

**N.B.:** I'm using the image **mongo:3.6** from the official dockerhub repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand why, but changing the running port from 27017 to 27020 worked fine. If someone passes by and can explain how, I'd be glad to hear his/her explanation as `netstat -tunelp` (as well a `ps aux`) while grepping port 27017 on both of my k8s nodes does not give any output related to port 27017...